# Can I ask on SO if there is an organization which officially classifies programming algorithms?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, scope

I would like to know whether there is a commonly agreed single place or organization that kind of officially classify programming algorithms. Something like the international organization of standards.

Is this a question I could ask on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Classifying programming algorithms? What does that mean? And no, asking for an external resource is pretty much off-topic on the entire Stack Exchange network.

Comment: I'm assuming the title is a question you'd like to ask on Stack Overflow? If so, it's unclear to me what you're even trying to ask.

Comment: I think the questioner wants to ask a question whether there is a commonly agreed single place or organization that kind of officially classify programming algorithms. Something like the international organization of standards.

Comment: @Trilarion exactly

Comment: @jitsCode Maybe the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420671/how-can-we-classify-various-algorithms) give you already some ideas without the need to ask a question yourself.

Comment: No, this question is not a good fit for SO.  It will be flagged and closed/removed.  The best place to look for such a question is Quora.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because (as Oded pointed out in his comment) you are asking for an external resource.

If you really must know the answer to this and Google<sup>*</sup> isn't helping then you could try asking in chat. While there's no guarantee of success, the discussion may help you refine your search terms so you can find what you want through Google<sup>*</sup>

<sup>* Other search engines exist</sup>

Answer (score 0):

From my side you can and I would even say that it is in a wider sense programming related. It might even fit a tad better to [Programmers StackExchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). And you might want to clarify what you mean by classifying. What classes would you like to have and how language specific or abstract should the algorithms be formulated?

edit: Okay, in the light of no external resources, then not.

Comment: No, no, no and again no.

Comment: @ChrisF One no was not enough. ;)